# how to rename Tree View node or change Tree View node using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I am using Tree View Structure in Java Script rename Node like parent or child Node.

I have code like that not working properly .

```
      function rename(TreeId , TreeNode)
{

         var selectnode  = Ztree1.getSelectedNode();


}
```

above var declaration i will get error like error alert message. can any one please let me how i can modify Parent Node and Child Node .Advance Thanks.**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

Add listener to tree, it works here for rename.

refer here [Rename a treeViewer Node with SWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921560/rename-a-treeviewer-node-with-swt)  not for java script but will give you idea